# Using the T-Mobile Edge Network on the Laptop

Tags: tethering, cellular-internet

I have EDGE on T-Mobile and I want to use that internet connection on my laptop. I think it is called tethering. Any ideas

Comment: It's tethering, btw.

Answer (score 0):

That highly depends on your cellphone... Usually you can just use the bluetooth interface to start sharing the internet with the computer. But mind you EDGE network can be fairly expensive.

Comment: I thought edge will be for a fixed price with unlimited download.

Comment: Well I don't know, but better confirm with ISP first.

Answer (score 0):

With a BlackBerry plan, there is no additional cost.  Under Windows, you can just use the BlackBerry Desktop Manager to set up your phone as a modem.  Under Linux, plug in a BlueTooth adapter and add your phone as a device, and you will be prompted to allow Internet connections through it.

For more detailed answers, give me more details.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your OS and Phone.

I have a Tmobile and its not EDGE, its 3G.
I have a n900, which under ubuntu I just plug in(via USB) and then it appears as a 3G/HSDPA modem under my wifi settings.

I would strongly suggest using a cable since you will get much better speeds.

*Also T-Mobile Unlimited is not actually Unlimited. Its normal up to 5GB and then they throttle the hell out of your connection.. and it stays at around 2-5kb/s